# Filter rsyslogd messages

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-server, rsyslog

I have a daemon that generates 15 - 20GB of logging each day. I want to use syslog (rsyslogd) to log all the messages. It is possible to redirect these messages to a file and not be printed /var/log/syslog?

I created a rule in /etc/rsyslogd/50-myprogram.conf that contains:

```
!MYPROGRAM
*.*     /var/local/myprogram/myprogram.log
!*
```

Now every message appears twice, in /var/local/myprogram/myprogram.log and in /var/log/syslog. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with:

```
if $programname == 'MYPROGRAM' then /var/local/myprogram/myprogram.log
& ~
```

The important thing here is: `& ~`, that discards the messages matched by the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if $programname == 'myprogram' then /var/local/myprogram/myprogarm.log
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it more useful for readers.

Comment: This is not all that was needed. Please see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stop rule in your config file.

```
 *.* stop
```

This will stop processing the log further. But make sure to include your config before  /var/log/syslog rule.